# Read csv row by row using java and concatenate as string

Tags: java

I have a CSV(2 columns) that has 1000 rows. The task I am working on is to retrieve a set of 100 first column rows and concatenate as a string( 'col1row1'+'col1row2'+'col1row3'+....+'col1row100' ). So this formatted string i will use as a parameter for a new function.

The following code only displays my CSV(having 2 columns) as an Array. Can someone help me here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
    String csvFile = "data.csv";
             File file = new File(csvFile);
             FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
             String line = null;
             String tempArr[] ;
             br.readLine();
             while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                tempArr = line.split(" ");
                
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(tempArr) + " ");
             }

             br.close();
             } catch(Exception ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
             }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] colArr= br. readLine(). split(" ");
    String col1= colArr[0], col2=colArr[1];
    while(...){
        tempArr= line. split();
col1Str += col1 + tempArr[0];
col2Str += col2 + tempArr[1];
     }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.